# std::map::erase(const key_type&) stop working after comparison customized

Tags: c++

I customize the comparison in std::map as below.

```
class my_cmp {
public:
  bool operator()(const string &a, const string &b) {
  return (a.length() >= b.length());
  }
};
```

`map<string, int, tmp_cmp> tmp;` works well with all key sorted per string length. But `tmp.erase("a string");` no longer works. Is there a solution to make the std::map::erase(key_type) still work after the comparison customized?

Comment: My map keys can have the same length. that's what I expect. But even I change to
    `class my_cmp {
      public:
        bool operator()(const string &a, const string &b) {
          if (a.length() == b.length())  
            return (a < b);
          else
            return (a.length() > b.length());
        }
    };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom comparator in `std::map` must have the same behavior as "less" operator. So, you have to change your code to something like `return (a.length() < b.length());`

Comment: yes. Actually { if (a.length() == b.length()) return (a < b); else return (a.length() > b.length()); } works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Chad's comment aside, I think your problem is that you include `=` in your implementation.

`map`'s definition of equality is `!less(a,b) && !less(b,a)`. This does not work for your definition of `less`.

Here is what Standard says in "23.2.4 Associative containers"

> 3 The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation
>   imposed by the comparison and not the operator== on keys. That is, two
>   keys k1 and k2 are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison
>   object comp, comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) == false. For any
>   two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling comp(k1, k2) shall
>   always return the same value.

Comment: btw, where can I find map's definition of equality?

Comment: Edited the answer to include standard reference.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator for a map must impose a **strict weak ordering**. In part that means that `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` cannot both be true. So comparisons should act more like `<` and `>` and not like `<=` or `>=`.